# How to insert relations based on a nested array in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables `tests`, `questions`, `options`.

As you can imagine

1. a test has many questions
2. a question belongs to a test
3. a question has many options
4. an option belongs to a question

These relations are set up in the models already.

I got the data from the front end in this form:

```
array:3 [
  "name" => "First Test"
  "preparation" => "First Test prep"
  "questions" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "title" => "Some question"
      "options" => array:4 [
        0 => "a"
        1 => "b"
        2 => "c"
        3 => "d"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "title" => "Another question"
      "options" => array:4 [
        0 => "e"
        1 => "f"
        2 => "g"
        3 => "h"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

This data perfectly represents these relationships. In fact if I were using a NoSql database I would simply store this in the database.

My question is "what is the best way to store all of this data at once while using eloquent in Laravel"?

**Note**: It is in the form of Laravel's collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Test extends Model {

    $table = 'tests';
    function questions(){
                return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'test_id');
            }

 }

class Question extends Model {

    $table = 'questions';
    function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'question_id');
            }

    function test(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Test::class, 'test_id');
    }

}

class Answer extends Model {

    $table = 'answers';

    function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'question_id');
    }

}
```

of course i showed only relations ,tables and foreign keys.
you can add any additional data to your models.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a structure of model objects from given data.
JMS Serializer is a great library to do that, and it has [laravel integration](https://github.com/atrauzzi/laravel-serializer).